# Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_xmyvjx04'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I compiled my ASP.Net files and uploaded them to my server (godaddy host) but I got this Run time 
Error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_xmyvjx04'. Make 
sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="movies, 
App_Web_xmyvjx04" %>
```

I have the file App_Web_xmyvjx04.dll uploaded in my bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify namespace.classname in your inherits and make sure App_Web_xmyvjx04 assembly is inside your bin folder.

Example:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="App_Web_xmyvjx04.movies, App_Web_xmyvjx04" %>
```